# Sum of Array value with the same Value

Tags: php

Hi I'm been working this problem for almost 2 weeks and I don't see any post blogs or tutorials that fit or may be an answer to my problem...

here is my problem...

Code:

```
foreach ($transHistory as $row) {

    $category[] = '{ y: '.$row->new_qty.', label: "'.$row->sku.'" }';

    $series[] = $row->new_qty;

    $nd = $row->createddate;

    $nd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($nd));

    $date[] = $nd;

}
print_r($series);
print_r($date);
```

in my code I got this array values

```
//array 1
Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 28 [2] => 07 [3] => 27 );
//array 2
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 14 [3] => 36 );
```

I want to get the sum of [0] & [1] from the array 2,
since [0] & [1] from the array 1 has the same value.

desired output:

```
// array 1
Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 07 [2] => 27 );

//array 2
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 14 [2] => 36 );
```

Comment: Yes I want that thing happen,,, Any Idea on how to do it ???

Comment: How are you getting this array? Maybe it's better to build it correctly from the start

Comment: I've done editing my question...

Comment: Does `$transHistory` come from a database?

Comment: Yes it does sir...

Comment: Let the DB do the work for you. It has functions, `SUM` and `GROUP BY`, that should be able to do this.

Comment: It is impossible for me to let my db do that because Our database designer make a table row datetime so meaning it will be useless event if I convert it to date because we are using ms sql server

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are saying there.

Comment: I think you're going to run into issues when there are multiple duplicates. e.g. `array(22,33,22,54,33,4)` when you remove the 22 dups and the 33 dups how do you know which one to sum in the next array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cooked this up on the fly, is this what your looking for?

```
<?php

$array1 = Array(28,28,7,27);
$array2 = Array(2,1,14,36);

sort($array1);
sort($array2);

for ($i = 0;$i < count($array1);$i++) {
  if ($i == count($array1) - 1) {
    break;
  } else if ($array1[$i] == $array1[$i+1] ) {
    $result = $array2[$i] + $array2[$i + 1];
    unset($array1[$i]);
    unset($array2[$i]);
    unset($array2[$i + 1]);
    array_push($array2,$result);
  }
}

// Testing Purposes
print_r($array1);
echo "<pre></pre>";
print_r($array2);

?>
```

Now here I am using unset to take the values out of the array, this means that if something was on $array1[3] and I unset it, that space still exists but un ordered. This is more or so an idea or a kick starter, it needs revisions to work perfectly.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 27
    [3] => 28
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [4] => 50
)

Comment: that's not my desired output but i think i can use it as a stepping stone for a solution

Comment: Awesome glad I helped a tiny bit!

Comment: Thanks bro I got what I need

Answer (score 1):

Following code will check in array $series for any duplicate values, if found then will sum the values exist in same index in $date array and will remove duplicate from $series array.

```
foreach ($transHistory as $row) {

    $category[] = '{ y: '.$row->new_qty.', label: "'.$row->sku.'" }';

    $series[] = $row->new_qty;

    $nd = $row->createddate;

    $nd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($nd));

    $date[] = $nd;

}

$date_new = [];
$temp=[];
foreach($series as $k=>$item)
{
  if(!in_array($item, $temp))
  { 
  $keys = array_keys($series, $item);
  $temp[]=$item;
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($keys as $key)
  {
    $sum+=$date[$key];
  }
  $date_new[]=$sum;
  }
}
$series = $temp;
$date = $date_new;
print_r($series);
print_r($date);
```

Comment: An error comes out with a message of "A non well formed numeric value encountered". It says it comes from this line $sum+=$date[$key]

Comment: @LorenceGarrido, It works fine for me with given values of array and returns the result as expected. If there is a case, that $date array can not have same keys as $series array, then we can add a non empty condition on $sum+=$date[$key]. Just add if(!empty($date[$key])) above this line.